# Problema com Leitura de Attribute no c#

Tags: c#, reflexão, atributos

estou com o seguinte problema, Tenho minha classe ENUM:

```
public enum DataBaseType
{
    DATA_BASE_NAME, SERVER_IP_NAME, PORT, USER_NAME, PASSWORD
};
```

Tenho o meu Attributo, no qual possui esse ENUM:

```
 public class Connect : System.Attribute
{
    public DataBaseType ValueType { get; set; }
}
```

Tenho minha classe de Conexao, sendo:

```
class ConnectionModel
{
    [Connect(ValueType = DataBaseType.SERVER_IP_NAME)]
    string ServerName { get; set; } = "localhost";
    [Connect(ValueType = DataBaseType.PORT)]
    string Port { get; set; } = "5432";
    [Connect(ValueType = DataBaseType.USER_NAME)]
    string UserName { get; set; } = "usuario";
    [Connect(ValueType = DataBaseType.PASSWORD)]
    string Password { get; set; } = "senha";
    [Connect(ValueType = DataBaseType.DATA_BASE_NAME)]
    string DatabaseName { get; set; } = "banco";
}
```

Tenho também a leitura dessa classe:

```
Type type = obj.GetType();
        foreach (FieldInfo field in type.GetRuntimeFields())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(field.Name + ": " + field.GetValue(obj));
        }
```

Até agora está tudo funcionando, porem agora preciso saber qual ValueType foi determinado para cada variavel, então faço o seguinte:

```
Type type = obj.GetType();
        foreach (FieldInfo field in type.GetRuntimeFields())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(field.Name + ": " + field.GetValue(obj));
            Connect attribute = field.GetCustomAttribute<Connect>();
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Is Not Null: " + attribute.ValueType);
            }
        }
```

o Problema é:
Toda hora o attribute está dando null, porque cargas dagua isso? onde estou errando?

Comment: eu pela pressa esqueci que também tem uma forma de recuperar propriedades com o modificador internal, no seu caso são atributos, mas, a visibilidade somente dentro então eu fiz uma alteração na resposta explicando, como pode contornar isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código para recuperar `atributos` de uma propriedade é feito recuperando suas propriedades e em cada propriedade buscar o seu atributo (pelo método `GetCustomAttribute`), **exemplo**:

```
ConnectionModel obj = new ConnectionModel();
Type type = obj.GetType();
foreach (PropertyInfo field in type.GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(field.Name + ": " + field.GetValue(obj));
    Connect attribute = field.GetCustomAttribute<Connect>();
    if (attribute != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(attribute.ValueType);
    }
}
```

nesse caso o código vai funcionar sendo que as propriedades estiverem configuradas como o modificador `public`, se não tiverem configuradas como `public`, serão `internal` então precisa colocar no `type.GetProperties` configurações para ter essa visibilidade, ***exemplo***:

```
type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
```

[Exemplo OnLine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k9NgoP)

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Acessando atributos usando reflexão (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/accessing-attributes-by-using-reflection)
- [How to get a list of properties with a given attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281972/how-to-get-a-list-of-properties-with-a-given-attribute)
- [Método Type.GetProperties ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aky14axb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class)
- [How to Use Type.GetProperties() in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-use-typegetproperties-in-c-sharp1)
- [Reflection, Type.GetProperties and performance](https://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/reflection-type-getproperties-and-performance/)
- [Properties Vs Fields In C#](https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/properties-vs-fields-in-c-6cec86c59dc9)